# Command line applications to list outgoing connections

Tags: network, command-line, monitoring

I am looking for a command line tool that is able to make a log of the outgoing connections.
I have already taken a look at the `nettop` command and it is really good, but the list of connections is updated in real time; due to this, I can't monitor quick operations like HTTP requests to websites or similar tasks.
Then, can you suggest me some tools with this mentioned feature?

Comment: There’s not a command line tool per se. what you want to do is set up a pf firewall rule to allow but log outgoing connections

Comment: @Allan, thank you for your suggestion. I’m going to take a look at the `pf` command manual.